# jQuery how to animate my code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, margin

Hey, I know a little bit of jQuery now, but I'm still a bit confused with animations (especially when I have to add them to working script).

I have for example:

```
  if (i = 1) {            
                i = i +1
                $("#div p").css("left", "-" + width * i + "px");  
        }
```

How to animate() margin adding? I'm trying and trying and trying...

```
     if (i = 1) {            
                i = i +1
                $("#div p").animate().css.("left", "-" + width * i + "px");  
        }

  if (i = 1) {            
                i = i +1
                $("#div p").css(.animate("left", "-" + width * i + "px"));  
        }
```

etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually want the margin to [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

```
$("#div p").animate({marginLeft: -(width * i) });
```

Or the left position?

```
$("#div p").animate({left: -(width * i) });
```

*(No need for the `"px"`, since that is the default for both of these. You don't need the quotes around the `"-"` either. You can send an integer.)*

Keep in mind that if you're animating the left position, you'll need to have your css position set to `relative` or `absolute`.

---

**EDIT:**

Also note that in your `if()` statements, if you are trying to do a comparison, you need to use `==` or `===`, as in:

```
if (i === 1) {...
```

Answer (score 3):

In the easiest way imaginable:

```
$('#book').animate({
    left: "-" + width * i + "px"
}, 5000);
```

Also, when in doubt, don't forget to take a look at the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/